# Как узнать Item рисунка?

Tags: vba

В ячейке xls есть рисунок. Как через vba узнать его Item чтобы потом обратиться к нему через Index, например ActiveSheet.Shapes(4)?

Comment: поставить макрос на запись, сделать что-нибудь с рисунком (например, передвинуть), остановить запись. в получившемся коде будет его номер.

Comment: Обсуждение вопроса на форума по Excel: https://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=1&TID=104482&TITLE_SEO=104482-kak-uznat-item-risunka-v-zadannoy-yacheyke

Comment: Спасибо slippyk. А как ПРОГРАММНО узнать Item всех рисунков, содержащихся в Range.